# SSRS Error after 240s

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

i observed a strange behavior of SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) 2016 on different machines with different reports and different data source types (SQL and OLAP).

In the table `[ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLogStorage]` are ca. 100 entries per month with `([TimeProcessing] / 1000) = 240` and `[Status] = 'rsProcessingAborted'`. The ReportServer logfile has for each row the entry:

> ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException:
>   , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be
>   due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the
>   database.;

Since there is enough space and the connection works in other cases it might be a timeout inside SSRS and i guess in the connection to the ReportServer database, but i don't know which one. The reports have specific configured timeouts (over 1 hour), so it's not the Report Server default timeout.

Which timeout is the cause of these report errors?

Comment: Looks liek you have the default timeout on the SSRS instances as 240 seconds; and hence any reoorts that take 240 to run are automatically stopped. You don't, however, ask a question here, so, what are you looking for? Can you [edit] your "question" and actually ask one please? :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not the report execution default timeout.

Comment: This could be an issue with the rendering engine connecting to the reporting database. ReportManager, as a web app, has it's session timeout configured in its web.config, however, it doesn't look like that type of error. Are there any timespan similarities between the times that the errors are occurring?

Comment: Out of interest, what is the value of `DatabaseQueryTimeout` key?